# Assigning architecture specific interrupt handler

Tags: linux-kernel, interrupt-handling

The "handle_arch_irq" function pointer is assigned in 2 places with interrupt handler.

[1st place:](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/1c163f4c7b3f621efff9b28a47abb36f7378d783/arch/arm/kernel/setup.c#L1158)

```
void setup_arch()
{
    handle_arch_irq = mdesc->handle_irq;
}
```

[2nd place:](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/1c163f4c7b3f621efff9b28a47abb36f7378d783/kernel/irq/handle.c#L219)

```
int set_handle_irq()
{
    handle_arch_irq = handle_irq;
}
```

The `set_handle_irq()` is called from `irq-gic.c`.

Can you help to understand why we are initializing at two places.

Comment: It is not initializing. If just store in two places a function. Why? I do not know, but probably because it is needed in some place where you do not have full kernel access (e.g. boot, or first stage of interrupt handler, or wake up routines, or ...)

Comment: In the 1st place `mdesc->handle_irq` may or may not be `NULL`. In the 2nd place, `handle_arch_irq` is only set if it is `NULL`. So `handle_arch_irq` is only getting set to a non-null function pointer once.

Comment: @IanAbbott, In the [1st place](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/1c163f4c7b3f621efff9b28a47abb36f7378d783/arch/arm/kernel/setup.c#L1158) if "mdesc->handle_irq" is NULL then how the interrupts generated during boot will handle? Can you help to understand this.

Comment: Interrupts won't be handled until the interrupt controller is set up.